# Markdown editor with folders as local libraries

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text-editor, productivity, markdown

I need beautiful editor that can 'import' *more then one* local folders as libraries.

This would let me *search* files only from these folders/libraries. But the crucial thing is to have local folders as libraries. It's important to not have the tool impose a custom folder structure, just simple folder and its files.

The tools I've dismissed for the job are as follows:

- http://writeapp.net/ - nice, but needs some issues to be fixed and more work to be put in.
- Ulysses, but I don't think it can use my folders as a libraries. EDIT: it is possible to add 'external source' to it, so for now this looks fine.
- nvAlt (not an editor, but has search), but it can work with just one folder

What software might work for my needs?

EDIT

I am not asking for common Editor. I do use Sublime on projects, but I want to use something else for my notes - simply because I want to access them in explained way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found only: Ulysses and WriteApp, as described in the question. Therefore I am marking this as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) with the [Markdown Preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) package.

It has Markdown syntax highlighting, color themes, and lets you treat directories as projects, allowing you to search over them, as you requested. The Preview package allows you to see the MD result in your choice of browser, with your choice of renderer (regular/GitHub).

Sublime is very versatile and open to many more customizations, should you require them.

Comment: I use sublime, but afaik you can't specify e.g. 3 different folders to be part of the same library. Moreover, when I use sublime on other projects, I can not access the first one.

Comment: Sublime can open a folder, not just a file - either select the top folder from within Sublime, or from the command line. I do not understand your second comment.

Comment: I need folderS, plural. I keep notes in eg: `~/prj/code`, `~/stuff/notes` etc. Second comments means that I can't have two projects open in the same time: when I open some project of mine, the first project (with notes) gets closed, right?

Comment: 1. Point Sublime at the top of the tree where your folders are
2. No - you can open several windows, each with its own project

Comment: I used TextMate for the last few years it did a great job now i'm testing out Atom.io (The Hackable Editor) it's development is still in Progress but it is already useble and a great plus if you know javascript/coffeescript you can personalize add functonallity and do really anything you want to it.

Comment: The least common folder is home, and that is out of question. I do not want _all_ files under the home to be notes. Sublime is not for this. Period :)